# Why are jiffies initialized at -300000 (5 minutes)

Tags: linux, time

I'm currently studying "Understanding the linux kernel" based on version 2.6.11.

At page 234: "You might suppose that jiffies is initialized zero at system startup. Actually this is not the case: jiffies is initialized to 0xfffb6c20 which corresponds to the 32-bit signed value -300,000; therefore, the counter will overflow five minutes after the system boot. This is done on purpose, so that buggy kernel code that does not check for the overflow of jiffies shows up very soon in the developing phase and not pass unnoticed in stable kernels."

Ok, it is for bug avoidance or better for early bug highlighting, but what happens to this buggy code? What happens if buggy code does not check for the overflow? Exception not managed? I mean, what happens when this buggy codes executes, and how a message is issued by 5 minutes?

Thanks, Diegus.

Comment: It seems the quoted passage exactly answers the question in the title.  Is there another question here?

Comment: Agree with @ChrisDodd. Additionally, though, "buggy" code can behave however.  It could crash your kernel, show errors, not work, erase your files, launch nukes... anything is possible, I guess.